# Which kind of AWS EC2 instance to use with ElasticSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

Usually the main factors to decide are:

- Is your system index intensive? Are you indexing a lot ?
- Are you performing a lot of faceting  and other search related functionality ?
- How many documents do you have?

In my case, we are doing the indexing once per day but our system is doing massive search functionality and we have a very large (massive) amount of documents.

By having a look at [Amazon EC2 Instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), I think the **"Memory Optimised R3"** is what I'm looking for but I appreciate if you share your personal experience.

Comment: R3 looks great, especially that it has SSDs ;-). Elasticsearch likes SSDs. Not sure how heavy your indexing is, though. I recommend `doc_values` for the eligible fields to make the most use of your memory, in case you do use sorting, aggregations on those fields.

Comment: What is the expected cluster size?

Comment: @helloV I would expect it to be something like 400 nodes.